# jQuery Scrollable или альтернатива

Tags: jquery

Всем доброго времени суток.
для библиотеки jQuery есть плагин, который позволяет делать скроллинг элементов.
http://flowplayer.org/tools/demos/scrollable/index.html
Пример использования.

```
<div class="scrollable">

   <!-- root element for the items -->
   <div class="items">

      <!-- 1-5 -->
      <div>
         <img src="http://farm1.static.flickr.com/143/321464099_a7cfcb95cf_t.jpg" />
         <img src="http://farm4.static.flickr.com/3089/2796719087_c3ee89a730_t.jpg" />
         <img src="http://farm1.static.flickr.com/79/244441862_08ec9b6b49_t.jpg" />
         <img src="http://farm1.static.flickr.com/28/66523124_b468cf4978_t.jpg" />
         <img src="http://farm1.static.flickr.com/164/399223606_b875ddf797_t.jpg" />
      </div>

      <!-- 5-10 -->
      <div>
         <img src="http://farm1.static.flickr.com/163/399223609_db47d35b7c_t.jpg" />
         <img src="http://farm1.static.flickr.com/135/321464104_c010dbf34c_t.jpg" />
         <img src="http://farm1.static.flickr.com/40/117346184_9760f3aabc_t.jpg" />
         <img src="http://farm1.static.flickr.com/153/399232237_6928a527c1_t.jpg" />
         <img src="http://farm1.static.flickr.com/50/117346182_1fded507fa_t.jpg" />
      </div>

   </div>

</div>
```

По сути, всё предельно просто. в контейнере items, создаётся контейнер, который содержит Н-ное количество элементов, ну и так далее. Количество элементов которое будет выводиться за раз, определяется количеством этих элементов в контейнере. В примере выше, всё предельно понятно.

Интересует вопрос, можно ли как - то сделать так, чтобы нужное количестно элементов выводимых за раз, задавалось где - то в JS коде, а не путём формирования HTML.

То есть, есть код:

```
<div class="scrollable">

   <div class="items">
         <div><img src="http://" /></div>
         <div><img src="http://" /></div>
         <div><img src="http://" /></div>
         <div><img src="http://" /></div>
         <div><img src="http://" /></div>
         <div><img src="http://" /></div>
         <div><img src="http://" /></div>      
   </div>

</div>
```

А количество выводимых за раз элементов уже прописываем где - то в коде.

Comment: Только что нашёл, что в ВЕРТИКАЛЬНОМ варианте скроллирования, этот плагин поддерживает такой функционал. Как бы его теперь применить горизонтально.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

параметр size за это отвечает

```
 <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $(".scrollable").scrollable({
                size        :       n,
            });
        });
  </script>
Плюс класс .items должен быть  очень большого размера (как все элементы)  и высотой в n-элемнтов, а .scrollable - шириной в  n-элементов и overflow:hidden
```

Comment: что - то я не могу понять суть. О_о  
больше слов пожалуйста.